# Git Tfs clone only showing the commits on the master branch

Tags: git, github, tfs

I've cloned a TFS repository into my local machine using git-tfs. I used the following command:

```
git tfs clone <server URL> <repository path> <local directory> --branches=auto
```

When I open the repository in source tree, I can only see the commits made directly to the master branch. `git log` is showing the commit history however, Source Tree only displays the master branch commits. I need to see the full history of commits made in all the branches but I've been unsuccessful in getting that.

**Edit:**

If I try to use `--branches=all`, I get some errors for that as well.

```
2021-04-19 10:46:19.9024 [Debug] git command time: [00:00:00.0468850] init
2021-04-19 10:46:19.9493 [Debug] No .gitignore file specified to commit...
2021-04-19 10:46:19.9493 [Debug] No .gitignore file specified to use...
2021-04-19 10:46:22.9008 [Debug] Looking for all branches...
2021-04-19 10:46:24.5489 [Debug] GitTfs.Core.GitTfsException: error: cloning the whole repository or too high in the repository path doesn't permit to manage branches!
   => If you want to manage branches with git-tfs, clone one of this branch instead :
```

```
PS:if your branch is not listed here, perhaps you should convert the containing folder to a branch in TFS.
   at GitTfs.Util.GitTfsCommandRunner.Run(GitTfsCommand command, IList`1 args) in C:\gittfs\src\GitTfs\Util\GitTfsCommandRunner.cs:line 36
   at GitTfs.GitTfs.Main(GitTfsCommand command, IList`1 unparsedArgs) in C:\gittfs\src\GitTfs\GitTfs.cs:line 83
   at GitTfs.GitTfs.Run(IList`1 args) in C:\gittfs\src\GitTfs\GitTfs.cs:line 48
   at GitTfs.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\gittfs\src\GitTfs\Program.cs:line 28
```

The branch structure is similar to the following:

```
  $/App/App.root/App [*]
 |
 +- $/App/App.root/backend/csv/Version-1.0
 |  |
 |  +- $/App/App.root/backend/csv/Version-1.1
 |  |
 |  +- $/App/App.root/backend/csv/Version-1.1/Fixes
 |  |
 |
```

When I use `git tfs` in `$/App` it only pulls the commits made in the master branch. I can't see the full tree with all the branches and their commits.

Comment: You don't give enough information on what you want to achieve, what is your branch structure, etc. Try https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/commands/list-remote-branches.md to find a branch to clone.

Comment: @Philippe Please see the edit.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--branches=auto` only initialize branches that are merged in `<local directory>`.

If you want everything, you should use `--branches=all`

Looking at your branch structure, the right command should be

```
git tfs clone <server URL> $/App/App.root/App <local directory> --branches=all
```

Comment: That was just one example. In this instance, `$/App/App.root/App` is just one branch. There are several others for example, `$/App2` and `$/App3`. Is there a way I can clone all the branches associated with `$/App` and '$/App2' etc at once rather than going through the branch structure and cloning them individually?

Comment: @Aithorusa Different applications should very likely be put into different repositories. Consider the differences between Git and TFVC when deciding how to structure your Git repos; putting everything into one giant repo is rarely the best approach.

Comment: @Aithorusa if all the branches are linked with $/App/App.root/App, they will be clone. Otherwise, no, that is not possible with git-tfs. But if they are not link, you can clone them in different repositories. And at the end fetch all the histories in the same repository and link all the histories if you want it...